# How to round up to the next integer?

Tags: java, math

What is the correct way to round a division of two integers up to the next integer?

```
int a = 3;
int b = 2;

a / b = ? //should give 2
```

Is `Math.ceil()` the right way to go?

Comment: or you can do (a+1)/b

Comment: @AakashGoyal, that only works for this specific case. What about 4/2, or 6/5?

Comment: you will get the same value, considering the output will be int. 4/2 -> 5/2 -> 2, 6/5 -> 7/5 -> 1

Comment: @AakashGoyal : does not work in most cases. (`b = 1`, or any `b - (a %  b) > 1`)

Comment: @Henry's answer works, on the other hand

Comment: Ohh yes, you are right...wont work in all cases, my bad

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, `Math.ceil()` won't work on its own because the problem occurs earlier. `a` and `b` are both integers, so dividing them evaluates to an integer which is the floor of the actual result of the division. For `a = 3` and `b = 2`, the result is `1`. The ceiling of one is also one - hence you won't get the desired result.

You must fix your division first. By casting one of the operands to a floating point number, you get a non-integer result as desired. Then you can use `Math.ceil` to round it up. This code should work:

```
Math.ceil((double)a / b);
```

Answer (score 36):

You can use this expression (assuming a and b are positive)

```
(a+b-1)/b
```

Comment: This is my favorite answer.
It works on any programming language.

Comment: When a = Integer.Max_Value and b = 1234, a + b will cause overflow，so (a -1) / b + 1 is better

Answer (score 6):

The return type of Math.ceil method is **double** where is, the return type of Math.round is **int**. so if you want that, the result will be in integer then you should use Math.round method, or else Math.ceil method is fine.

```
float x = 1654.9874f;     
System.out.println("Math.round(" + x + ")=" + Math.round(x));   
System.out.println("Math.ceil(" + x + ")=" + Math.ceil(x));
```

### Out put

```
Math.round(1654.9874)=1655

Math.ceil(1654.9874)=1655.0
```

Answer (score 3):

a division between 2 integers (also known as `integer division`) yields the remaining of the division.

```
3/2 = 1
```

To use ceil, you need to make a division that is not integer.:

You can either declare your values as doubles (`3.0`or `3d`) or cast them before dividing:

```
((double) 3) / ((double) 2) = 1.5
```

This double value can be used in ceil.

```
Math.ceil(3.0 / 2.0) = 2.0;
```