# The calculations on my code aren't working any reason why? We have to find the square feet of a room, and find how much paint it needs 1gallon=350sqft

Tags: java, calculation

We have to find the square feet of a room and determine how much paint it needs. The paint gallon coverage 350 square feet. For some reason, my code isn't working in the calculations. I know the problem is in the "if/else" statement, I just don't know what. I made an if-else statement to say that if the square feet is under 350, then to just make the gallons needed, 1. Just because we shouldn't leave it in decimals since it's supposed to be if you go to the store, you can't by the decimal size. Thanks

```
//import java scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

//declare variables
class Main {
  final int  COVERAGE =350; //paint covers 350sq. feet
  int length, width, height;
  double totalSqFt, paintNeeded;
    //declare integers length, width, height
    //declare doubles totalSqFt, paintNeeded
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  //this will run all the main methods
  public void runProgram()
  {
    input();
    calculations();
    output();
  }
  
  //this will get the user input for the length, height, and width of the room
  public void input()
    {
    System.out.println("Length of room:");
    length = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Height of room:");
    height = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Width of room:");
    width = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
        //Prompt for and read in the length of the room
        //Prompt for and read in the height of the room
        //Prompt for and read in the width of the room
  }
  
  //this calculates the user data for the amount of paint needed 
    public void calculations()
  {
    totalSqFt = height*width*2+height*length*2;

    if (totalSqFt < 350){
      paintNeeded = 1;
    }else{
      paintNeeded = (int)(totalSqFt / COVERAGE);
    }
        //Compute the total square feet of the walls to be painted
        //Computer the amount of paint needed
    }

    //this prints out the calculations above
  public void output()
  {
        System.out.println("Length: " + length + " Width: " + width + " Height: " + height);
    System.out.println("Total Square Feet: " + totalSqFt + " \nGallons of Paint Needed: " + paintNeeded);
    //Print the length, width, and height of the room and the gallons of paint needed.
    }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Main prog = new Main();
    prog.runProgram();
  }

}
```

Comment: What is your input values and expected result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round up to the next integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689128/how-to-round-up-to-the-next-integer)

Comment: You probably want `paintNeeded = (int) Math.ceil(totalSqFt / COVERAGE);` so that it rounds UP to the nearest integer and you are buying the correct number of paint cans.